# "NameError: name 'encode' is not defined " while trying to format an object to json. I have an issue if I try to do it using JSONEncoder as well

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'am trying to turn an object into json format by creating a function to first turn that object into a dictionary, which then can be formatted into json.
I have also tried to seperate the two functions in the first script into two different classes. So one class with a function to return the object as a dictionary and the other class to provide the conditional statement. Though that doesn't work either. By the way this wasn't included.

```
import json

class person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age


bob = person("Bob", 5)


class encode_Obj:

    def encode(x):
        if isinstance(x, person):
            return {"name": x.name, "age": x.age}
        else:
            raise TypeError("Object of type user is not JSON serializable")


bob_JSON = json.dumps(bob, default=encode)
print(bob_JSON)
```

I've also totally scratched out that idea and instead tried using JSONEncoder but then it gives me "TypeError: Object of type person is not JSON serializable." Which is the same error it will give if whatever is being formatted into json is not a dictionary, but instead just a normal object. And to note, the returned format doesn't have to be a dictionary, it can be a list for example.

```
import json
from json import JSONEncoder
class person:
def __init__(self, name1, age1):
    self.name1 = name1
    self.age1 = age1

bob = person("Bob", 5)


class obj_to_json(JSONEncoder):

    def default(self,x):
        if isinstance(x, person):
            return {"name": x.name1, "age": x.age1}

        return super().default(x)

bob_JSON = json.dumps(bob, cls=obj_to_json)
print(bob_JSON)
```

Feel free to ask for any needed clarificaton.

Thank you.

Comment: The method definition is correct, but you want to override `default`, not `encoder`.

Comment: The two scrips are two different ways of doing it, which were you talking about and if overriding encoder is still the answer could you show me?

Comment: `json.dumps(bob, default=encode())` -- which `encode()` function do you want to call there?

Comment: You don't want to *call* the function at all; you want to pass it to `dumps` to call when needed.

Comment: The question remains, where is that function?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I've already addressed that in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to subclass `JSONEncoder` is to override `default`. (`encoder` isn't an existing method; it's not overriding anything and thus not being used.)

```
class obj_to_json(JSONEncoder):

    def default(self, x):
        if isinstance(x, person):
            return {"name": x.name1, "age": x.age1}

        return super().default(x)
```

Your first attempt, with `encode_Obj`, had two problems: one, you try to use a function named `encode` rather than the instance method of your `encode_Obj` class; and two, you *called* the function and passed its return value as the `default` argument, rather than passing the function itself. Instead, try

```
def encode(x):
    if isinstance(x, person):
        return {"name": x.name, "age": x.age}
    else:
        raise TypeError("Object of type user is not JSON serializable")


bob_JSON = json.dumps(bob, default=encode)
```

Comment: I have updated the question and the second script will work. Thank you you guys!